# How to use go-lang server as both file server and back-end logic server

Tags: go

In php we can host application and use the same server,port to handle the back-end logic calls.

I've used the following way to achieve this in go-lang. Is there a better way to achieve this?.

```
r := mux.NewRouter()

http.HandleFunc("/dependencies/", DependencyHandler) //file serving

http.HandleFunc("/portals/", PortalsHandler) //file serving

r.HandleFunc("/registeruser", UserRegistrationHandler)

r.HandleFunc("/deleteuser/{username}", DeleteUserHandler)

http.Handle("/",r)

s := &http.Server{
    Addr:           ":" + strconv.Itoa(serverConfigs.HttpPort),
    Handler:        nil,
    ReadTimeout:    time.Duration(serverConfigs.ReadTimeOut) * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout:   time.Duration(serverConfigs.WriteTimeOut) * time.Second,
    MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `Subrouter` method on Gorilla's `mux` - specifically in here - http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux (which I can't link to internally). The example around using `PathPrefix` to separate your 'sub-routers' is likely what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serve static files and implement your backend logic handlers with mux router. Use PathPrefix() and StripPrefix() for that:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.PathPrefix("/portals/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/portals/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./portals/"))))
    r.PathPrefix("/dependencies/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/dependencies/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./dependencies/"))))
    r.HandleFunc("/registeruser", UserRegistrationHandler)
    r.HandleFunc("/deleteuser/{username}", DeleteUserHandler)
    http.Handle("/", r)

    log.Println("Listening...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r)
}
```